# Is it true that the probability that an "almost prime" is prime, tends to $0.59$?

Tags: probability, number-theory, functions, prime-numbers

According to the estimation of the number of rough numbers I found in Wikipedia, the number of integers from $1$ to $x$ with no prime factor below $x^{1/u}$ tends to $\omega(u)\frac{x}{\ln(x^{1/u})}$ , if $x$ tends to $\infty$, where $\omega(u)$ is the Buchstab function.

I concluded that the probability that a number $x$ without a prime factor smaller or equal to $x^{1/3}$ (Let us denote such a number "almost-prime", although this name might be a sysnonym for a semi-prime) tends to 
$\frac{\omega(3)}{\ln(x^{1/3})}$ , if $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Since the probability that a number $x$ is prime tends to $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ , if $x$ tends to $\infty$, this implies that the probability that an "almost-prime" is prime tends to $\frac{\ln(x^{1/3})}{\omega(3)\ln(x)}=\frac{1}{3\omega(3)}=\frac{1}{3\cdot 0.564382}=0.5906$

> Are my thoughts correct ?

Calculations seem to backup the claim that the probability tends to roughly $59$% :

```
almostprime(n)={local(w);w=factorint(n);w=component(w,1)~;w=w[1];w>sqrtnint(n,3)}

? q=0;r=0;for(m=10,100,if(almostprime(m)==1,q=q+1);if(isprime(m)==1,r=r+1));prin
t(r,"    ",q,"     ",r/q*1.0)
21    32     0.6562500000000000000000000000
? q=0;r=0;for(m=100,1000,if(almostprime(m)==1,q=q+1);if(isprime(m)==1,r=r+1));pr
int(r,"    ",q,"     ",r/q*1.0)
143    216     0.6620370370370370370370370370
? q=0;r=0;for(m=1000,10^4,if(almostprime(m)==1,q=q+1);if(isprime(m)==1,r=r+1));p
rint(r,"    ",q,"     ",r/q*1.0)
1061    1667     0.6364727054589082183563287343
? q=0;r=0;for(m=10^4,10^5,if(almostprime(m)==1,q=q+1);if(isprime(m)==1,r=r+1));p
rint(r,"    ",q,"     ",r/q*1.0)
8363    13608     0.6145649617871840094062316285
? q=0;r=0;for(m=10^5,10^6,if(almostprime(m)==1,q=q+1);if(isprime(m)==1,r=r+1));p
rint(r,"    ",q,"     ",r/q*1.0)
68906    113951     0.6046985107633983027792647717
? q=0;r=0;for(m=10^6,10^7,if(almostprime(m)==1,q=q+1);if(isprime(m)==1,r=r+1));p
rint(r,"    ",q,"     ",r/q*1.0)
586081    977543     0.5995449816529809941864449953
? q=0;r=0;for(m=10^7,10^8,if(almostprime(m)==1,q=q+1);if(isprime(m)==1,r=r+1));p
rint(r,"    ",q,"     ",r/q*1.0)
5096876    8559062     0.5954946932268979941960929831
?
```

> Can we expect that the probability will soon tend to $0.5906$, if we continue ?

I do not expect a strictly motontone decreasing probability, but it should reach a value near $0.5906$ and then maybe oscillating around this value.
Can this be proven ?

Comment: Yes (although "soon" may not be that soon, the convergence of these things can be quite slow).  What part of your analysis are you worried is unproven?

Comment: In particular, I am unsure whether the estimate is good enough for , lets say, $x=10^{50}$. I did not find any bounds how large the error term is. But I am glad, that my conclusion seems to be valid :)

Comment: Where you have "tends to [some function of $x$]", the more correct term would be "is asymptotic to". "tends to" tends to be used synonymously with "converges to".